# Регулярное выражение по поиску всех символов кроме некоторых

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
/([а-яё])/ig
```

как усовершенствовать данное регулярное выражение, чтобы оно дополнительно находило **различные символы**, кроме точки(.), нижнего подчеркивания(_), тире(-), слеш(/), звездочка(*), скобок().
Пробовал сделать хотя бы вот так, но не находит ничего:

```
/([а-яё].(\.\_\-\/\*\(\)))/ig
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все символы кроме `.`, `_`, `/`, `*`, `(` и `)`:

```
/[^\._\-\/\*\(\)]/
```

В [русской версии MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-sets) это именуется: "отрицательный или дополнительный набор символов"

И пример удаления из строки всех символов кроме указанных:

```js
var regex = /[^\._\-\/\*\(\)]/g;
console.log("aAбБ1!@%#%:;'\"+._-*()[]{}".replace(regex, ""));
```

Comment: почему в таком выражении возвращается $1, а не окрашенный символ: return el.toUpperCase().replace(/[^\._\-\/\*\(\)0-9a-z]/ig, '<span style="color:red;display:inline-block;background:yellow">$1</span>');

Comment: @ikar потому что у вас нет первой группы. Оберните `[...]` в скобки: `([^\._\-\/*()0-9a-z])`.

Answer (score -1):

Решение на python3.

```py
import re

text = '<img src="https://vk.com/image/svdf...">'

regular_expression = re.compile("<img.+png.>")
message = regular_expression.sub('hello', text)

>>> 'hello'
```

Comment: И как это отвечает на вопрос ТС? Вы его прочли?

Comment: Зачем на python, если вопрос про js